# ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName returns empty array on Simulator

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, addressbook, abaddressbook

When using the standard iOS simulator address book, `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName()` doesn't return any results when searching for any of the names such as "Appleseed".

On the device it works fine. And retrieving all records using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()` works as well on the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the composite name field isn't correctly populated for the Simulator database. When editing the "John Appleseed" record once it's subsequently found by `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName()`. The same applies to the other standard records.

Filed a bug as [rdar://19889491](http://www.openradar.me/19889491).